# jquerymobile automatically use position:fixed if its finds ios5

Tags: jquery-mobile, ios5

Or I do I need to set it up myself? I'm using a fixed footer and it looks ok in ios4 but obviously want to utilise position:fixed if available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually specify that touchOverflowEnabled should be enabled - [check the docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html) - since according to them not everything works as smooth as it should and they wanted to leave the developers the choice until everything stabilizes.

Hope this helps!